# What aspects of the physical and metaphysical aspects of human existence limit humans from perceiving all of reality?

Tags: physics

It might be a naive question, but just like light, which in a way has a ‘cosmic trait’ of the constant speed of 299,792,458 m/s, due to which light cannot perceive time; so similarly is it possible that humans, due to how we exist or what we are made of (for example, the particles of matter we are composed of) have some kind of 'cosmic trait' that makes us not able to perceive some phenomena of universe?

---

Edit- apologies, i think my question does not exactly says what i meant to ask, I meant ,in a way that there could be certain cosmic traits that does not allow us to feel something regardless of our senses, for example light cannot perceive time because for that speed there could not be something like time. So, therefore in a way the universe does not allow the light to perceive time, so similarly if something like this could be applied to other things in the universe which may including us, that due to some cosmic trait without which that thing cannot exist(which is associated to us like for light its the permanent speed of it and it cannot exist without having that speed)its the laws of universe does not allow us to perceive certain things and due to this we or anyone(regardless of living or not) who falls into a certain trait cannot experience it.

Comment: If possible, please try to proofread your post for grammar, spelling, punctuation, typos, etc. It makes it easier for us to read, understand, and help you. Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Of course, our perception is limited: it is confined to the thresholds of the five senses.

For instance, water is not transparent in certain spectra, so we can't perceive its opacity. We can't perceive the entirety of the universe, the past, the minuscule, the immense, the fast or the slow; we are unable to perceive entities such as aliens made of neutrinos, which could potentially be right in front of you at this very moment.

In simple words, what you know (knowledge) is a map of the terrain, not the terrain itself. And, as any common map, it is useful, but it doesn't hold even an infinitesimal portion of reality. Knowledge is not a copy of the world, it is a very simple abstraction, built upon our limited potential of perception.

Answer (score 0):

There is physical limit to seeing the unobservable universe due to the expansion of the universe preventing distant light reaching us.  "The unobservable Universe must be ... over 15 million times as large as the volume we can observe." [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2018/07/14/ask-ethan-how-large-is-the-entire-unobservable-universe/)